# Do you think the following sentence illustrates future?

Tags: word-usage, future-tense

I want to talk about my **future goal**.Do you think the following sentence illustrates that?

> I have an intention to continue my researches and works exclusively in car industry.

Thanks

Comment: It's wordy; "I intend to..." would be better. And you want the infinitive *work*, not *works*.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks.You mean,I should change it to "my research and work"?

Comment: Yes, having an intention indicates something you want to do in the future. @StoneyB read your sentence as [continue my research] and [work in the car industry], but maybe you meant you want to continue your [research and work] in the car industry. Both are fine, but if you mean to use the nouns, singular forms are fine. Also, "car industry" lacks an article: _the car industry_ would be fine. Bonus: _automotive_ is a nice alternative for car in this case, depending on your audience.

Comment: @oerkelens Good point. Gotta be careful when you're dealing with 'zero-derived' nouns!

Comment: trust me... I REMOVED the article and automotive industry from my answer! @oerkelens

Answer (score 4):

> I have an intention to continue my researches and works exclusively in car industry.

Yes, this indicates the future: "intention" indicates a plan for the future "continue" indicates something going beyond the present.

However, there are problems with the sentence.

- "I have an intention" suggests that you have all kinds of other intentions, too. This is probably true but, if you were applying for a job, for example, it would be better to say "I have the intention", to focus on the one intention that's relevant to the job. But, as mentioned in the comments to the question, "I intend to" is a simpler and more natural construction.
- "my researches and works": normally, "research" and "work" are singular, non-count nouns. Sometimes, it makes sense to talk about "researches" as individual pieces of research, but "my research" is more natural in most cases. Likewise, if you were a composer, you might talk about your "works" meaning the individual pieces of music you've composed but, in most situations, it's more natural to talk about your "work", meaning all the things you've done.
- "in car industry" should be "in the car industry". "In industry" would be fine (as distinct from "in academia" or "in government") but, as soon as you qualify it with an adjective or modifying noun, it's "the car industry", "the chemical industry", "the airline industry", etc.
- Also, as pointed out in the comments to the question, there's a slight ambiguity as to whether you mean "I intend to continue my research and I intend to work exclusively in the car industry" or "I intend to continue my research and my work, and I intend to do that in the car industry."  I suppose it doesn't much matter, since the two meanings are almost the same. If you wanted to remove the ambiguity, you could rephrase as "I intend to continue my research and to work exclusively in the car industry" for the first version and "I intend to continue my research and work, exclusively in the car industry" for the other.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with StoneyB.

> I intend to continue my researches and works exclusively in the car industry

is okay! Mind the definite article *the*.

But, I'm not putting this as a comment because I think, *works* is fine. We often use *researches and works* to show academic excellency.

Say a book's title

> [Reports of Radio Researches and Works in Japan](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Reports_of_Radio_Researches_and_Works_in.html?id=D6I1AQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)

or a sentence from the news site the [DailyStar](http://www.thedailystar.net/the-curse-of-ctrl-c-and-ctrl-v-15240)-

> While other countries follows a stringent policy to prevent this crime to have more original ***researches and works,*** our policy makers and academicians seem to be unaware of it.

Comment: These plurals are acceptable (marginally) with respect to past publications, particularly those of many authors; but I would not accept your last quote, which is unidiomatic. And OP's intention is not specific publications but the activities *work* and *research*, which are non-count.

Comment: You said you removed the article from your answer, but _in car industry_ doesn't sound fine to me at all. As for using the plural nouns, you may want to specify _we_; I doubt that in AmE or BrE these plurals would feel natural.

Comment: @oerkelens strange. I find no problem with that. *My works and researches* are [absolutely okay](http://people.clarkson.edu/~mol/resources.php) as PHD scholars describe it. And enlighten me, what's the issue with *...in the car industry*?

Comment: There is no issue with _in the car industry_, there is an issue with _in car industry_! "My works" usually refers to works of art and it is rare to be used for someone's _work_ in general, which is an ongoing process and as such uncountable. _Researches_ also refers to individual pieces of _research work_, whereas _my research_ refers to the process of doing research. In the context of _continuing_ those things, the singular form (with an uncountable meaning) is much better fitting. You should, at least, specify that your proposed usage is localized Indian English, as your sources suggest.

Comment: @MaulikV If I were you, I'd ask that as questions. By the way, I think you have two unrelated questions.

Comment: @oerkelens The *researches* can be used with [any person](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/research?searchDictCode=all). Which part of OP's question makes you think that *researches and works* don't fit. *He is known for his works and researches in the automotive industry* looks actually healthy. Maybe, InE problem! :)

Comment: He is _known for_. AmE and BrE speakers will assume those are _finished_ works and researches. That is why, to them, it makes little sense to _continue_ them as in the OP. If your proposed usage is InE, that is fine, but it should be clearly mentioned :) And I _still_ insist on including an article before _car_!

Comment: By the way, your book title is 1) a translation from Japanese, 2) as far as I understand, talking about finished pieces of work and finished researches, not ongoing activity, and 3) published in 1931, over 80 years ago. I am not sure it illustrates your point very well ;)

Comment: I have never thought that my question could be this much controversial.:) I assume that these details are related to tastes of people than grammatical rules.I want to write this sentence for a Finnish person.Do you think for an non-American or non-British these details are important?

Comment: @Khashayar: the article _the_ in front of _car_ **is** important, whatever your audience. And I _think_ the general consensus is, that for most flavours of English, with the possible exception of InE or 1930's Japanese-influenced English, using the plural _works_ and _researches_ is not a good idea unless you mean they are finished (but then, how can you continue them?) In general,  you are free to use whatever dialect you want, but your audience is likely to expect either AmE or BrE. Any deviation from that can be seen as "wrong".

Comment: @Khashayar anything that comes to ELL goes deep into the matter! That's the beauty of the site. In fact, at times, things leave me thinking, "Ah, did I really mean that!" :)